# Python "startswith" not working when string is a variable passed to the function

Tags: python, python-3.6, startswith

In my main function I have a tuple containing a list of search values. I am trying to search for each of these values in a data array one by one. In my main function I pass a data array (pulled from a text file) along with the specific value to be searched to my search function.

A stripped down version of my code is below. The .startswith fails to find the string when it is passed to the function through "v". If I manually define the string however it works without issue. I have checked the string multiple ways to verify that it is a string, is the correct lenght, no missing characters etc. and can't find any issues.

Any ideas?

```
def find_ends(data, v):

    for line_no, line in enumerate(data):
        if line.startswith (v):
            start = line_no
    return start


def main():

    fr =open('filename', 'r')
    data = fr.readlines()
    fr.close

    arraynames = ["TOPOGRAPHY:", "XCOORD:"]

    for v in arraynames:
        start = find_ends(data, v)

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Show the data. There shouldn't be any difference in functionality when a string is passed as an argument vs used outside of a function. The more likely answer is the data is different than what you're expecting. Different casing, a loose space/newline. There could be subtle differences that you're missing.

Comment: Also, you're never calling `close`. You're just referencing the function. Not the problem here, but just a note.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It is possible that you need to remove the space where I've added a hash symbol.  Depending on the editor, I've seen the placing of a space between the method name and the bracket "break" it. ***line.startswith#(v)***    I note that you have no space when using the enumerate(data) call or the find_ends(data, v) calls... this might just be the cause

Comment: Making a sample file to test this with, the code you've provided seems to work fine. Look closely at the difference between this "stripped down" version and your original version to find what changed. Did you add a return statement? Is there whitespace that you ought to be stripping off, as in `line.strip().startswith(v)`?

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful suggestions. As usual, the code just started to work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helpful comments. As usual the code just seemed to start working, not sure why. Here's the final code, maybe someone can spot what happened!

The data looks like below. The script looks for a line containing the keyword and the number of corresponding lines/values below it. The script then determines the relevant start and end lines in the file/array which will need to be copied later and returns this info to the main function.

```
TOPOGRAPHY: 25  
0.000
0.000
0.000
0.000
...
XCOORD: 25
0.000
2.500
5.0
...
...
```

---

```
def find_ends(data, v):

    for line_no, line in enumerate(data):
        if line.startswith (v):
            parts = line.split()
            start = line_no
            records = int(parts[1])
            end = line_no + records
    print(start, end, records)      
    return start, end, records

def main():

    fr = open('file', 'r')
    data = fr.readlines()
    fr.close

    arraynames = ["TOPOGRAPHY:", "XCOORD:"]

    for v in arraynames:
        start, end , records = find_ends(data, v)  
        print(start, end, records)  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```